# Bootstrap 3 datepicker and moment issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have 2 [bootstrap 3 datepickers](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on a page. One is the issue date the other the due date. I want to set the `due_date` to `issue_date + transactionDaysTerms` (`14` days for example).

```
    $('#issue_date').datepicker({
    }).on('changeDate', function(event){

        $(this).datepicker('hide');
        var calculatedEndDate = moment($('#issue_date').val()).add(transactionDaysTerms, 'days');
        $('#issue_date').datepicker('setEndDate', calculatedEndDate);
        $('#due_date').datepicker('setEndDate', calculatedEndDate);

    }).on('clearDate', function(event){
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', today);
    });
```

I have tried various formats with `moment` to no avail. This code fails with

```
Uncaught TypeError: date.match is not a function
```

How can I get the date formatting from moment.js to work with the datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly.

```
    $('#issue_date').datepicker({
    }).on('changeDate', function(event){
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
        var calculatedEndDate = moment($(this).datepicker('getDate')).add(transactionDays, 'days').toDate();
        $('#issue_date').datepicker('setEndDate', calculatedEndDate);
        $('#due_date').datepicker('setDate', calculatedEndDate);
    }).on('clearDate', function(event){
        var calculatedEndDate = moment(today).add(transactionDays, 'days').format('L');
        $('#issue_date').datepicker('setEndDate', calculatedEndDate);
        $('#due_date').datepicker('setDate', calculatedEndDate);
    });
```

I just needed `.toDate()` at the end of the moment call.

Comment: No, you needed to use `.datepicker('getDate')` and not `$('#issue_date').val()`, which means my answer works just fine as well. I did change it a little as `setDate` doesn't seem to accept a timestamp for some reason, but only another date object.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use `getDate` to get the timestamp from the datepicker, and then multiply the days to get milliseconds, add it up, and set the end date

```
$('#issue_date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(event) {

    $(this).datepicker('hide');

    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var days = transactionDaysTerms * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    var calculatedEndDate = new Date( date.getTime() + days );

    $('#issue_date, #due_date').datepicker('setEndDate', calculatedEndDate);

}).on('clearDate', function(event) {
  $(this).datepicker('setDate', today);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/LcqM7/517/)

Comment: Hi @adeneo, it does not work as the date is pulled in this format Wed Sep 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time) from the picker.

Comment: No, the date should be a javascript object, if you do `console.log( typeof date )` what do you get

Comment: The [docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#getdate) are quite clear as well ... *"Returns a localized date object representing the internal date object..."*

Comment: `console.log( typeof date )` returns `undefined`. The datepicker `getDate` returns Fri Sep 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time).

Comment: How can it be `undefined` when it's right there? Did you add that console.log inside the event handler, right after `var date = ...`

Comment: And no, it doesn't return that, that's how your browser console displays a date object, by stringifying it.